# Title font in appbar is not changing in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'soshia',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text('soshia', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Festive')),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: Icon(Icons.chat),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code. I have tried a lot but i am not able to understand why the title font of my appbar is not changing. I have saved the font .ttf file in fonts folder. I have also updated my pubspec.ymal code. Below is my pubspec.ymal. Please help.

````
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

fonts:
  - family: Festive
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Festive-Regular.ttf```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to add theme attribute to the material widget so you can use this font family all over the widget:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'soshia',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Festive',),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text('soshia'),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: Icon(Icons.chat),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

}